# Найти и заменить текст во всём документе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как найти и заменить текст во всем документе? 
Например

```
<div > qweqwe</div>
<img scr="img/qweqwe.jpg" >
```

Поменять qweqwe на asdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("span, p, div").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("qweqwe", "asdf");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Проходимся по всем `span`, `p` и `div` и меняем текст в них.

Атрибуты, разумеется, не трогаем. Поэтому в `img` у вас имя файла так и останется прежним (надеюсь, вам не надо так же и атрибуты и теги переименовывать).

Comment: Ладно, пример в вопросе очень простой (скорее даже вырожденный), а как быть, если картинки внутри дивов и параграфов?